# How to convert String variable to ControlType

Tags: c#

I have a String variable that contains control type. Example: "Button", "TextBox" or "Label". I want to get PropertyInfo from this Variable. I have run this code but in first line return Null:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(ControlType);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Type.GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires an assembly qualified name, and is case sensitive.

So for a windows forms app it would be in the format:

```
Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`
```

For webforms it would be the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace, etc.

Comment: what is type "formsAssembly" variable ?

Comment: @Mohadeseh_KH Assembly. But I've removed that bit anyway as `LoadWithPartialName` is [marked as obselete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'other systens'?

Comment: i mean that other version of Visual Studio..example lower or higher